# Can the calibration-discrimination decomposition of Brier score be viewed as the bias-variance decomposition of mean squared error?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, calibration, bias-variance-tradeoff, scoring-rules

The mean squared error has a famous decomposition into bias and variance.

$$
\text{MSE} = \text{bias}^2 + \text{var}
$$

Brier score is also a mean squared error calculation, and Brier score has a decomposition into measure of how well the model is calibrated and how well the model can discriminate between categories.

Can these decompositions be related to each other?

Comment: Consider this description https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/bias_variance_decomp/

Comment: @Ggjj11 Could you please point to where that discusses calibration and discrimination?